# VB.net How to copy object from inherited class

Tags: vb.net, object, copying

I have ClassA with some member data s1 and s2
I also have ClassB which inherits ClassA and has its own member data s3 and s4

Now I instantiate ObjectA from ClassA and populate the member data s1 and s2

Next I instanitate ObjectB from ClassB.

Question: How do I copy ObjectA member data to ObjectB without having to copy each of ObjectA member data to ObjectB member data?

Comment: You could use AutoMapper ( https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper , also available as Nuget package ).

Answer (score 0):

If you mark each member with an Attribute (eg, make a MemberMapAttribute that has a TargetMember property), then you could use reflection on your source object to get the property maps and do the copy.